# 4 prong Dryer cord not quite in all the way

Tags: dryer

I've seen similar questions on the inter webs, but in a lot of cases I think users had the wrong dryer power cord. In my case I have a 4 prong cable and a 4 prong receptacle. Despite lots of rocking and pushing, I can see maybe  1 mm of the prongs and the plug is (obviously) not snug against the receptacle.

Do I need to have an electrician replace the receptacle? Has anyone ever seen this but eventually got the plug in 100%? I've been trying for 15 minutes and haven't been able to get it.

Comment: 1mm is barely enough space to fit a credit card, is that really all the space?

Comment: Yes, I would say that a credit card might not even fit in the space.

Answer (score 2):

If it is only 1mm you have it in as far as it will go, good contact is being made. Your concern is what? The blades of the plug start engaging their receivers in the outlet almost as soon as the blades enter the receptacle. Lots of contact.

To answer your question, no you do not need to replace the outlet, IMHO.